# Styling textfield: iOS style

Tags: iphone, css, ios, text, textfield

I wanted to make my own WebApp for testing so I will know what to do when I've got some serious stuff to do. I found some info about using HTML, CSS and Javascript to make the web app look like real iOS but one thing that bugs my mind is hot to make the textfield look like the one iOS uses or at least similar to that and how to make it across the whole screen (width) but with some margins on the left and right... well so it looks nice and naturally.

I appreciate every single answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what textfield in iOS you're referring to? Do you mean something like this: http://homepage.mac.com/madcran/IMG_0001.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you could try is checking out [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) which let's you develop iPhone/iPad/Android (and even Mac/PC) applications using just HTML/CSS/JavaScript. It allows you to utilize the native UI elements, including forms, lists, buttons, etc...

If you're thinking of developing mobile apps, this is a pretty cool tool to use (especially if you're not a Object-C wizz).

One example of a tool that uses Titanium is [WunderList](http://www.wunderlist.com/) to-do application.

Comment: Well I really like the Appcelerator, it looks awesome! I'll give it a try, thanks ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a lot of fun and a great way to start mobile dev. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use jquerymobile or sencha touch... depending on whether you're familiar with ExtJS or not. That way you can focus on adding in your content, not messing around with CSS forever to try and simulate something you'll replace with iOS eventually anyway.

http://jquerymobile.com/

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Comment: I looked at the sencha and also found this book for developing apps in HTML, CSS and JS where jqtouch was mentioned and I liked it quite a bit more then those two. But I'll still think about these as the Appcelerator Titanium looks still quite better then all of these... But thanks for your tip ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using the `-webkit-border-image` CSS property. Even if you're using some kind of framework that does all that stuff for you, it's always nice to know how it's achieved under the hood, as it's always re-applicable somewhere else.

Ref: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-border-image